# how can i record in Xcode 9 (for UI testing)

Tags: xcode, xctest

I can't find the record button in Xcode 8 (for UI testing, I didn't find any help online [it's not in the debug bar]).

where is it or how can I record?

Answer (score 0):

[image: record UI test button]

It's down at the bottom near the breakpoint toggle. The button is deactivated until your text input is within a XCTest UI function.

Comment: "text input" == your cursor/focus in the IDE